# Change background color of div on even/odd dates

Tags: javascript, css

I have a repeating list of div lines as table with some dates in the first columns, as this example:

```
<div>
  <div>20 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>20 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>21 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>22 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>22 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>22 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>23 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>24 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>24 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>25 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>26 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
</div>
```

I need to format any line with an odd day with a background color, and an even day with another, like: all divs with 20, 22, 24, 26, with gray; and 21, 23, 25 with white (date outputs comes from php formatting). Please note that not all dates are necessarily one single line, the number of lines may vary.

Of course, CSS or Javascript, anything is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not a coding service, what have you try some far ? .. here we don't provide requirements and wait for *ready-to-go* codes, here we help people that already did an effort

Comment: What have you tried so far and what seems to be the problem with your current attempt(s)? Please update your question and include the source code you have tried.

Comment: you can add a php check in each div like 20%2==0 then add style of  gray color else other color

Comment: @OmerMuhammad why would you suggest a language that isn't tagged in the  question and why server-side? This can be done very easy with some simple `javascript`

Comment: @NisargShah read question carefully before duplicating :) don't simply read some words.

Answer (score 3):

```js
// get all immediate child divs
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div > div');

// loop through them
[].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
  var num = parseInt(div.innerHTML);

  // if it's an odd number, gray the background of that div
  if (!isNaN(num) && num % 2 === 1) {
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div>20 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>20 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>21 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>22 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>22 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>22 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>23 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>24 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>24 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>25 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>26 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.main{
  background:#FF0;
}
div:not(.main):nth-child(2n+1) {background: #CCC !important}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>20 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>20 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>21 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>22 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>22 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>22 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>23 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>24 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>24 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>25 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
  <div>26 Dic</div><div>Anything</div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure why this getting upvoted but it has nothing to do with the question ... please read it again